# Firefox shows Fixed Background, Chrome shows scrolling background

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, scroll, background, fixed

maybe someone knows how to fix this properly?
I have my website made with Wordpress.
The source page is exactly the same, but there's a problem with the pages background whereas it shows fixed on Firefox (and also sized correctly / cover) on Chrome it's zoomed in and it's scrolling with the page.

Page sample:
[Website here](https://www.laforetdesrenards.com/portfolio-item/hotcouture/)

Chrome is famous for this issue apparently but I wonder if there's an efficient workaround to solve and see my backgrounds on their original scale (and also responsive on devices of course)

Thanks for letting me know,
Bruno

I cannot find a solution because the code is literally the same, it's just the browser responsiveness that changes

Comment: Please read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/354577)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the code (attached):

[image]

CHROME:

```css
.edgtf-parallax-row-holder {
  height: auto!important;
  min-height: 200px!important;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-position: center top!important;
  background-size: cover
}
```

FIREFOX

```css
.edgtf-parallax-row-holder {
  position:static;
  padding:0;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-color:transparent;
  background-position:center 0;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-transform:translateZ(0);
  transform:translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform:none;
  overflow:hidden
}
```

The problem is that Chrome is forcing to refuse the "cover" tag, and also if I try changing the background attachment from "scroll" to "fixed" is not staying in place.